# Matlab mex c: strange calculation error with long double

Tags: matlab, gcc, mex

I've noticed a problem on some C code that I'm writing where when I multiply two long doubles I sometimes get lower than expected accuracy. I've isolated an example below, note that this is an mex file for use in matlab. Repeating exactly the same code in pure c results in the expected behaviour.

```
#include <mex.h>
#include <stdint.h>
typedef int32_t q0_31; // 32 bit signed fixed point number with 31 fractional bits

// conversion to long double from q0_31
long double q0_31_to_ldouble(q0_31 d) {
    return d/2147483648.0L;
}

/* The gateway function */
void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
              int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    mwSize nInputs = 0;
    mwSize nOutputs = 0;
    q0_31 b;
    long double b_ld;

    /* check for proper number of arguments */
    if( nrhs!=nInputs )
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("filter_interface:nrhs","wrong number of inputs!");
    if( nlhs!=nOutputs )
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("filter_interface:nlhs","wrong number of outputs!");

    // random value for b
    b = 0x81948b0e;
    // convert to long double directly
    b_ld = b/2147483648.0L;

    mexPrintf("Inline calculation...\n");
    mexPrintf("b_ld:\t%0.16LA\n",b_ld);
    mexPrintf("b_ld^2:\t %0.16LA\n",b_ld*b_ld);

    // repeat with sub function
    b_ld = q0_31_to_ldouble(b);

    mexPrintf("Exactly the same with sub function...\n");
    mexPrintf("b_ld:\t%0.16LA\n",b_ld);
    mexPrintf("b_ld^2:\t %0.16LA\n",b_ld*b_ld);

}
```

After compilation, this is the output I get from the code:

```
Inline calculation...
b_ld:   -0XF.CD6E9E4000000000P-4
b_ld^2:  0XF.9B7D0E4BEE0D3100P-4
Exactly the same with sub function...
b_ld:   -0XF.CD6E9E4000000000P-4
b_ld^2:  0XF.9B7D0E4BEE0D0000P-4
```

It is totally bizarre, the value returned by the function is exactly the same as the inline calculation. Yet when I square it I get a different result.

As I only get this behaviour in the mex and not when I compile the same code directly with gcc I thought it might be due to some strange compiler flag that matlab uses. But I have not been able to find anything.

Any ideas? Can anyone replicate?

MATLAB Version: 7.14.0.739 (R2012a)

gcc: 4.8.1-10ubuntu9

Comment: Is your mex -setup using the same compiler? Can you try printing out `sizeof(double)` and `sizeof(long double)` to see if the mex is just mapping the latter to doubles. Is your squared value larger than `realmax('double')`?

Comment: I cant even reproduce the same results using Visual C++, but that's probably because they simply [map](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9cx8xs15.aspx) `long double` to `double`! Here are my results running R2013b with VS2012: http://pastebin.com/F3xCKrC4

Comment: @Amro I think that you are right, I get the same results if I change the code to use doubles rather than long doubles

Comment: @horchler I'm using gcc for mex compilation and the same for the direct version. sizeof(double) is 8 and sizeof(long double) is 16. The squared value is lower than realmax('double') but the original integer b is 32bit (1bit sign and 31 digits) which means that the square needs 62bits to be fully stored. Double only has 52bits for the fractional part so cannot store the full accuracy.

Comment: A shot in the dark. Does anything change if you call the sub-function first and then do the inline calculation? Also, maybe try to make separate variables for each. Finally, try adjusting optimization flags. What doe the mex use and are you using the same compile command and flags?

Comment: fwiw, you can use `cc = mex.getCompilerConfigurations` to get the current compiler configurations, including compilation/linking flags: `cc.Details.CompilerFlags` and `cc.Details.LinkerFlags` (this is basically the info stored in your `mexopts.sh` file when you run `mex -setup`)